# Automate to initiate DocuSign documents

Tags: trigger, docusign

I'm familiar with how DocuSign (still learning) sends document but I'm not sure how docuSign can be initiated automatically to send the documents when certain Opportunity gets to a certain stage, is there a way you can fire the docuSign send documents?

Comment: did you the Apex Trigger for doing this? Can you please share your solution

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with the Docusign API.

I would do this by utilizing a trigger and the API. On trigger event, call the  you would utilize the DocuSign API (specifically the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms call if you have templates in there as well) to load up the document in the code along with the template and any other info you need and send it over to Docusign.

I'm not sure if it's possible to do with just the UI, but definitely possible with code.

Comment: Can you plaese suggest me on the https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260482/embed-the-docusign-with-the-email-notification-sent-using-the-apex-trigger I have a trigger that sends Quote as an email attachment but need to add Docusign in the attached PDF for the end users to sign